# "No kidding" and "not kidding"

Tags: negation

What is the difference between *not kidding* and *no kidding*?

Is *no kidding* valid English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrases mean roughly the same thing in most contexts, but are used slightly differently (*not kidding* requires mentioning *who* isn't kidding, whereas with *no kidding* it is implicit). There are many ways these phrases can be used in colloquial English, including:

*This may be hard to believe, but I'm honestly not joking*:

> There was a goose in our kitchen - no kidding! (*or* I'm not kidding!)

*Really? You're not joking?*

> -There was a goose in our kitchen!
>
> -No kidding?! (*or* You're kidding me?!)

*I couldn't agree more; Yes, I know, I experienced it myself.*

> -It must have been hard for you to go without food for six weeks!
>
> -No kidding! (*or* You're not kidding!)

*Don't fool around*

> No kidding around now please!

Answer (score 4):

"No kidding" means "I agree," while "not kidding" means "I'm not joking." "No kidding" could also mean "no joking allowed."

It is valid English, but only in certain registers.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference between "no kidding" and "not kidding" is that "no kidding" can be used as an interrogative.

Speaker A

```
I just won a million dollars!
```

Speaker B

```
No kidding?
```

Speaker A

```
I'm not kidding!
```

Answer (score -1):

If we see both phrases one by one

``No kidding '' >like a teachers is teaching in a class, and ordering the student. That no kidding in a class. .

While in the second situation 
'Not kidding'' Ram explained to Rama that is not kidding. (means he just explaining the situation,)

Comment: "No kidding" *can* be an instruction not to kid, but that is not the common use of the expression.

Answer (score -2):

> Is no kidding valid English?

It is, in American English. It is not really used by English and other British people.

This question should be tagged as American English.